# TypeScript and MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, typescript

I was wondering for some feedback with which javascript MVC library TypeScript is working "well" together. I am new to Javascript/TypeScript and have no specific needs, just want to get my code organized through some MVC framework. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works really well with AngularJS. I have a bunch of video tutorials on the subject : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-6vT7xgE4Y&hd=1

AngularJS has really good support for TypeScript : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs

Comment: Thanks a lot Basart, i will have a look at your videos when i have proper internet connection ... Do you know about some written tutorials on the subject?

Comment: Hi Basart, just watched the video, very impressive. I am too new to AngularJS/TypeScript but that video definitely convinced me more to let TypeScript - AngularJS be my framework. Will now try to get d3 to work within that setup, should be a smooth step. Thanks again

Comment: One question comes up when I look at the resulting out.js. The variable "Controllers" is defined several time, once for each controller. When the js file are merged as in this setup is there a way to clean this up automatically so that the variable is only declared once? Or to declare it in some central place. Thanks

Comment: @dorjeduck I believe this addresses it : https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts/issues/9 see my answer

Comment: Thanks basarat for your instant reply - really love the ease of the setup you created